# Is there a modern equivalent to JParanoia, or any free online Paranoia software in general?

Tags: tools, online-roleplaying, paranoia

Although I'm a massive fan of all things tabletop roleplaying, there's always been a soft spot in my heart for Paranoia. I now have a small group of people interested in running some tabletop roleplaying, but we'd ideally be doing it online as meeting in person regularly isn't viable.

There used to be a pretty popular piece of software for running it online called JParanoia, but last I checked that was no longer being maintained and doesn't really work on modern systems (I couldn't get it to work at least).

I've had a look online to see if there are any alternatives, but googling "Paranoia online" just had streaming links for the movie, and adding "tabletop" to the search just gave me some mission generators but nothing that would actually facilitate the playing of a campaign.

Obviously if all else fails I can just try to use something like RollD20, but I wanted to check first whether anyone knew of something specifically for Paranoia or that would work well with the system.

Comment: Roll20 is quite efficient as a "online table" and already have Paranoia sheets available. Is there a special feature you're looking for? (I don't know the rules of Paranoia)

Comment: Mainly support for tracking the secret society missions/mutant powers and things like that.